# Nested React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need some help to accomplish routing in ReactJS.
I describe my problem and hope you can help me..

I have famous index.js in this file and I call app.js from it

```
**index.js** 

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

inside app.js I wrote some code for routing as below :

```
**App.js**

return (
        <div>
            {message &&
                <div className={`alert ${type}`}>{message}</div>
            }
            <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Main} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={SignIn} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
```

this work correctly and after login I redirect to Main.js

and now my problem :

I`ve written some route in Main.js page that all other pages must inherit from that. I mean all other page must have the skeleton of Main.js

here is some code of Main.js

```
**Main.js**

<main className={classes.content}>
    <Link to="/HomePage"> HomePage</Link>
    <Link to="/Admin"> Admin </Link>
    <Link to="/Menus"> Menu </Link>
    <Link to="/Product"> Product </Link>
    <div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/HomePage" component={HomePage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/Admin" component={Admin} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/Menus" component={Menus} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/Product" component={Product} />
    </Switch>
</main>
```

unfortunately none of this routes works..
I`m extremely confused because all of things seems right

Comment: what version of react-router you are using?

Comment: react-router-dom : v 4.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

None of your nested paths are an exact match to "/" rendered by the `PrivateRoute` of the main router, so they are not rendered.

## Solution

Place the parent routes in a `Switch` and reorder the routes so the "/login" path can be matched before the more general "/" path. Remove the `exact` prop from the `"/"` path.

**App.js**

```
return (
  <div>
    {message &&
      <div className={`alert ${type}`}>{message}</div>
    }
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={SignIn} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Main} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```

**Main.js**

```
<main className={classes.content}>
  <Link to="/HomePage"> HomePage</Link>
  <Link to="/Admin"> Admin </Link>
  <Link to="/Menus"> Menu </Link>
  <Link to="/Product"> Product </Link>
  <div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />
  <Switch>
    <PrivateRoute path="/HomePage" component={HomePage} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/Admin" component={Admin} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/Menus" component={Menus} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/Product" component={Product} />
  </Switch>
</main>
```

Comment: oh thank you. and another mistake I think was about <div> inside Router. but I cant imagine why i was wrong...?

Comment: @Cawboy A div inside a `Router` is ok since routers inclusively render all matches, but a div inside a `Switch` would cause an issue as the div would be "matched" instead and everything inside would stop being matched for anything. The `Switch` component should render only `Route` (or variations like custom `PrivateRoute` etc...) or `Redirect` child components.